# How to pool a thrift client (or at least reuse the tcp connections) in java

Tags: java, thrift

Is there a standard library for thrift in java that will facilitate the reuse of tcp connections for many rpcs that are being issued. It seems that thrift does not support pipelining requests on a single connection (though correct me if I'm wrong), but it seems like it would be greatly beneficial to be able to reuse a thrift tcp connection when one rpc is done with it. How can I achieve this most easily?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can use any general purpose pool to cache thrift clients.

For NodeJs, there is thirft-pool project on npm which is based on generic-pool. It's pretty good except they pool connections instead of clients which means you have to create a new client from a connection each time.

For java client, I am using my own object pool for this, you just need to provide a thrift factory. (https://github.com/DanielYWoo/fast-object-pool)

We also use a general pool for python clients.

Comment: Any example of how to use it with thrift?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library that helps use Thrift client with pool.
You can check my project here:
https://github.com/minhlong293/thrift_client_pool/tree/master

If you have any questions, feel free to ask me.